# How to make DataModel with multiple-input-file in mahout?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, mahout, datamodel, mahout-recommender

I want to make DataModel with numerous *.csv files.(these have same format, different data)
But, I have no idea how to do that. 
I cannot find function through mahout documentation.(mahout-API)
"Make module that makes numerous *.csv file to one *.csv file" only solution?
please help...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine all of you *.csv file, i.e combine two files as below

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("YOUR_SOURCE_1"));
    BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("YOUR_SOURCE_2"));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("YOUR_TARGET");
    int x = 0;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (x > 0) {
            String [] values = line.split("\\t", -1);
            writer.write(values[0] + "," + values[1]+","+values[2]+"\n");
        }
        x++;
    }
    String line;
    int x = 0;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (x > 0) {
            String [] values = line.split("\\t", -1);
            writer.write(values[0] + "," + values[1]+","+values[2]+"\n");
        }
        x++;
    }
    reader.close();
    reader2.close();
    writer.close();
}
```